# UseState how to set an Array back to empty?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I'm trying set `clickFavIconArray` back to an empty array with the hook.

Basically, the `setClickFavIconArray` has a list of IDs the `showFavIcon()` checks that ID and if it contains the same ID I want to remove it from the array and update the `setClickFavIconArray` to the new Array.

However, it just seems to be adding on to the original `clickFavIconArray` no matter what. Is there a way to clear the `clickFavIconArray` state back to an `[]` empty array?

Some help here would be awesome.

```
const [clickFavIconArray, setClickFavIconArray] = useState([]);

    function showFavIcon(id){
        if (clickFavIconArray.includes(id)) {
            const newArray = clickFavIconArray.filter(item => !id.includes(item))
            setClickFavIconArray(newArray)
        }
            setClickFavIconArray([...clickFavIconArray, id])
    }
```

Comment: Are you intending just to say, `setClickFavIconArray([])`?

Comment: you are filtering the array, updating the state and immediately after (two lines lower) you are appending the id again to the array? maybe I do not understand the problem, but does it help if you add a return statement after the first setClickFavIconArray(newArray)?

Answer (score 1):

Simply pass the new value of empty array to `setClickFavIconArray()`:

```js
setClickFavIconArray([])
```

Comment: this answers the OP's question regarding the title but does likely not solve his problem?

Answer (score 1):

To make sure that the id is not immediately added to the array again, add a return statement inside the if-statement.

```
const [clickFavIconArray, setClickFavIconArray] = useState([]);

function showFavIcon(id){
    if (clickFavIconArray.includes(id)) {
        const newArray = clickFavIconArray.filter(item => !id.includes(item));
        setClickFavIconArray(newArray);
        return; // make sure that the next line is not executed
    }
    setClickFavIconArray([...clickFavIconArray, id])
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues with the code

1. filter function seems to be invalid it should be replaced with

```js
clickFavIconArray.filter(item => id != item)
```

2. You are adding id again to the array with this

```js
setClickFavIconArray([...clickFavIconArray, id])
```

If you want to remove id, there is no need for this line in your code.
However you can always set `clickFavIconArray` to an empty array state using this code:

```js
setClickFavIconArray([])
```